# Do I have to restart after a library update on Linux?

Tags: linux, library, glibc

Yesterday's CVE-2015-7547 lead me to the question whether I have to restart all applications and services linked to glibc after installing the glibc update?

Or more generally, in terms of security, is it advised to restart all applications or services using a library when this library received a security update? Or might it even be better to restart the whole computer?

Comment: If you have something Debian-based, look at checkrestart from the packet debian-goodies.

Comment: On OpenSUSE you can use `zypper ps` to find programs that need to be restarted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After an update of a library it is necessary to restart all applications which use this library, because otherwise they will continue to use the old version. In case of updates to very fundamental libraries like libc this is probably done best by restarting the whole system.